# what version of dll files are loaded by Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dll

When I start PowerShell ISE in Windows 10, I can run the following code

```
$dt = new-object "system.data.DataTable";
```

I know this is only doable because System.Data.dll is loaded, otherwise, there will be an error as [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) class is from System.Data.dll

On my computer, I have multiple versions of .Net framework installed, such as v4.6.x, v4.7.x

So my question is, once my PowerShell starts

1. how can I know what DLL files are loaded?
2. what are their versions ?

Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command, shown with sample output from my Windows 10 machine running PowerShell v5.1:

```
PS> (Get-Item ([System.Data.DataTable].Assembly.Location)).VersionInfo | Format-List    

OriginalFilename  : system.data.dll
FileDescription   : .NET Framework
ProductName       : Microsoft® .NET Framework
Comments          : Flavor=Retail
CompanyName       : Microsoft Corporation
FileName          : C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
FileVersion       : 4.7.3160.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
ProductVersion    : 4.7.3160.0
IsDebug           : False
IsPatched         : False
IsPreRelease      : False
IsPrivateBuild    : True
IsSpecialBuild    : False
Language          : English (United States)
LegalCopyright    : © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
LegalTrademarks   :
PrivateBuild      : DDBLD202B
SpecialBuild      :
FileVersionRaw    : 4.7.3160.0
ProductVersionRaw : 4.0.30319.0
```

- `[System.Data.DataTable]` is a type literal (an object representing the type whose full name is given)
- `.Assembly` returns an object representing the assembly that contains the type.
- `.Location` returns that assembly's file path.
- Passing that file path to `Get-Item` outputs a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object representing the assembly file.
- That `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object has a `.VersionInfo` property returning the version-info details.
- Piping to `Format-List` shows the version-info details in list form, with each property printed on its own line.

Note that there are ***two* version numbers**:

- The ***CLR* (common language runtime) version number**, as reflected in `Version.ProductVersionRaw` (`4.0.30319.0`) (but seemingly also indirectly in the *file path*, `v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089`)
- The ***Framework* version number**, as reflected in `VersionInfo.ProductVersion` (`4.7.3160.0`)

Typically, multiple success *framework* versions are built on the *same CLR* version; e.g., both frameworks v4.6.x and v4.7.x are built on CLR v4.x.

Note that not all `System.*` types necessarily report the exact same *framework* version, but the *CLR* version they report is by definition the same.

---

Use the following to extract only the *framework* version number, as a `[version]` object, by directly accessing the `ProductVersion` version-info property:

```
[version] (Get-Item ([System.Data.DataTable].Assembly.Location)).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

This yields, for instance:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      7      3160   0
```

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @jyao. Glad to hear the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you only care about currently loaded assemblies you can use

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerSh
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_
```

If you care about referenced assemblies it gets complicated.

```
$loaded = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
$referenced = $loaded.GetReferencedAssemblies() | select-object -Unique
```

That will get all loaded assemblies and all referenced assemblies. The issue is that the referenced assemblies aren't all loaded so this only gets you AssemblyName object.

```
$referenced
Version        Name
-------        ----
4.0.0.0        mscorlib
4.0.0.0        System
3.0.0.0        System.Management.Automation
4.0.0.0        System.Core
4.0.0.0        System.Xml
4.0.0.0        System.Configuration
```

To get the rest of the details you can use reflection.

```
$referenced = $loaded.GetReferencedAssemblies() | select-object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoad($_)
}
$referenced
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configurat
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryS
```

Note that a lot of these are probably already loaded so you would need to get the assemblies that are loaded and remove them from the referenced list.

```
$referenced = $loaded.GetReferencedAssemblies() | select-object -Unique | `
    ForEach-Object {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoad($_)
    } | Where-Object {
            $loaded.FullName -notcontains $_.FullName
    }
```

Now the referenced list is only referenced assemblies that are not loaded.

```
$referenced
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Manag
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JSc
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Servic
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Re
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Bui
```

Note though that these may have referenced assemblies that are not loaded as well. So you would need to build a recursive function to iterate through them repeating the above methods if you care to dig that deep.

Comment: Thanks @StephenP, your answer is also great, esp. from a generic, big-picture perspective, so I can know all loaded DLLs, I believe your answer will help lots of people in future days !